# How to specify default diff tool for 'git add'?

Tags: git

On a sever I'm working on, the `git diff` behavior has been customized via some lines in $HOME/.gitconfig

```
[diff]
    renamelimit = 2093
    guitool = diffmerge
    external = $HOME/git-diff-wrapper.sh
    submodule = log
```

But, in some one-off runs of `git add` I need the normal default behavior. How do I specify options at the command line to temporarily restore the *default behavior*, i.e. what do I put after the `=`s?

```
git -c diff.guitool= -c external= diff
```

I tried blanks and `''` and it doesn't seem to work. It might have to do with that `external` is not (or no longer) a documented valid option.

Comment: For a git command `git foo`, you can use `git -c key=value foo` to specify one or more configuration values which take effect for this run only. For example, `git -c core.pager=more log`, `git -c user.name=me -c user.email=me@xyz.com commit`.

Comment: @ElpieKay: Thanks! Why not turn it to an answer so I may properly accept it as an answer?

Comment: Actually, when the default values are desired for all possible options, what would one specify after the `=`s? Just leave blanks (`git -c diff.guitool= diff.external= diff.submodule= diff`)?